# GWT Browser distinction in Client

Tags: java, gwt, browser, user-agent

I try to find the current Browser for an specific Hack in GWT.

like: *(View-class)*

```
if( GWT.getBrowserName().contains("IE") ) {
    // DOM.setElementPropertyBoolean( ...  Hack
}else {
    // normal stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a ugly solution:

Creating a class for each bowser and mapping it in the `gwt.xml`

```
public class BrowserIE6 extends Browser {
    public boolean isIE6() { return true; }
    public boolean isIE7() { return false; }
    ...
}
```

```
<replace-with class="com.project.client.style.BrowserIE6">
    <when-type-is class="com.project.client.style.Browser" />
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
</replace-with>

<replace-with class="com.project.client.style.BrowserIE7">
    <when-type-is class="com.project.client.style.Browser" />
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie7" />
</replace-with>

...
```

But is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't see why this solution is ugly, it's even recommended in the official docs http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html.

Comment: Why not create separate "view" classes and use deferred binding to load the appropriate view for the browser?